# Custom Bottom Navigation Bar Item Decoration in Flutter

Tags: flutter, user-interface, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I am trying to build something like this
[UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hzihQ.jpg)

In this the selected Bottom Navigation Bar Item should be highlighted with a background color.

Currently, I've done this:

```
bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        fixedColor: Colors.black,
        currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
        showSelectedLabels: false,
        showUnselectedLabels: false,
        onTap: _onItemTapped,
        items: const [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home_outlined),
            label: '',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.checklist_outlined), label: ''),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.file_copy_outlined), label: ''),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.notifications_outlined), label: ''),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.settings_outlined), label: ''),
        ],
      ),
```

Comment: You can check out this package and see if it meets your requirements. This package has alot of styles: https://pub.dev/packages/persistent_bottom_nav_bar

Answer (score 1):

If you want the selected tab to have yellow background color when selected, one way is to wrap the icon with a Container and set color based on _selectedIndex

```
icon: Container(
  width: 40,
  height: 40,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    color: _selectedIndex == 0 ? Colors.yellow : Colors.transparent,
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(200)
  ),
  child: Icon(Icons.home_outlined)
)
```